# POST object send to PHP from Angular is empty, Get and Server is responsing

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I've been stuck in this for a couple of days. I try to consume a site from an Angular through the HttpClient Module and so far I have passed the CORS with the headers and the server responds to my requests but I need to send data by post, if I print the server response it prints GET, REQUEST and SERVER without problems but POST It is returned as an empty object. I have reviewed some documentation and tested some configurations but I have not succeeded.
Has anyone faced a similar situation?

My postData

```
  postData = {
    usuario: 'admin@localhost.com',
    password: 'securePassword',
    texto: 'This is a Simple Text'
  };
```

My Angular Function

```
  testConection(postData) {

this.http.post(
  this.url,
  postData,
{responseType: 'text'} /* {responseType: 'json'} */
)
.toPromise()
.then(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

My PHP function code

```
  public function post()
    {
        $response['POST'] = $_POST;
        $response['GET'] = $_GET;
        $response['SERVER'] = $_SERVER;
        $response['REQUEST'] = $_REQUEST;
        $response['COOKIE'] = $_COOKIE;
        $response['ENV'] = $_ENV;
        
        // echo json_encode($response);

        print_r($response);
```

Headers in PHP & .htaccess

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

Responsing in Console.
[Responsing in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwALe.png)

Comment: // Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);

Comment: Thanks, file_get_contents('php://input') fixed my problem